# Cannot access nw globals in Chrome app

Tags: requirejs, google-chrome-app, node-webkit

If I run a simple Chrome App within nw.js, and use the console in DevTools I don't have access to any of the extra nw objects.

According to the [docs](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/JavaScript%20Contexts%20in%20NW.js/#global-objects-in-browser-context):

> Some objects of Node context are copied to Browser context so that
>   scripts running in Browser context can access Node.js objects

This includes `nw` and `require`. These objects are undefined if I try and log them in the console.

I can also see that there are errors thrown by some of the nw.js internal scripts

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Window' of undefined
    at get_nw (extensions::nw.Window:753:20)`

What do I need to do to access these objects in my Chrome App?. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't using a package.json but was using the Chrome App's manifest.json file. The Chrome App loaded but the extra objects weren't available. Got rid of the manifest.json and added the necessary fields to the old package.json and it all works.